# How to save Multiline TextInput value separately in mysql 5 db

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

This is my TextInput:
[InputArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttdfu.png)

I want to save textInput values separately

```
const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('')

      <TextInput
        multiline={true}
        style={allStyles.textInput}
        placeholder="Type Here"
        onChangeText={setTextInput}
        value={textInput}
      />

console.log(textInput);
```

the input text will be like this:

```
360-654-3438
309-395-3513
248-277-2718
951-288-7491
770-886-9060
203-332-2145
```

i want the console log result be like this:

```
{
    number: 360-654-3438,
    number: 309-395-3513,
    number: 248-277-2718,
    number: 951-288-7491,
    number: 770-886-9060,
    number: 203-332-2145
}
```

and save them to my database separately by a for loop or something like that.

the rest of the code will be like this:

```
for (let number of textInput) => {
  axios.post(`[address]/save_numbers?number=${number.number}&account={account.id}`)
}
```

Comment: What is your MySQL **precise** version? *and save them to my database separately by a for loop or something like that.* Do you want to say that you need in sending this one multiline must insert a lot of rows?

Comment: @Akina mysql version 5 and yes. one row for each number. and a relation to the one who added numbers.

Comment: Query cannot on your version. Use stored procedure, iterationally parse and insert in it.

Comment: @Akina I dont want save query, i want send them to db by axios separately. one post for each number in query. just want to separate each line

Comment: I.e you want to split the value to an array/collection of single rows? this task is not relative to database at all, you have tagged the question as MySQl-relative wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textInput.split("\n").forEach((e) => {
axios.post(`[address]/save_numbers?number=${e}&account={account.id}`)
})
```